# Issue with the URL when opening the modal window in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In the Twitter Bootstrap documentation which can be found [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html), scroll to the section Modal - NOTE - scroll and do not click on the sidebar to immediately jump to that section.

Now here, under Live Demo (scroll some more in the Modal section), click on the "Launch Demo Modal" button. Now, notice the URL - it does not change and the modal window is displayed. Close it and no change again in the URL.

My application however behaves differently - it shows the the URL succeeded with the id of the modal window (in the example, it would be myModal). Thus the URL, if it were my application, would be twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#myModal - notice that the ID is appended to the end of the URL - but it does not happen so in the Twitter Bootstrap Documentation example. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the bootstrap-modal.js script? In the "MODAL DATA-API" section, the e.preventDefault() should stop the browser from navigating to the href specified in the a tag.

Comment: I am using `bootstrap.js` which as I understand contains all the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery.js before than bootstrap.js!!

And do not use simplified form of html for script. (like `<script scr=""/>` ) have to close it like `<script scr=""></script>` )

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- BootStrap Link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/linker/styles/vendor/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/linker/js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Have you called `$('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');` this after the document is ready?

```
$(function() {
    $('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');
});
```